# The contact form is still getting submitted after implementing 'preventDefault' in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-5

"I have a contact form that I only want to submit when the fields are validated. However, there are instances where it works, and other times, blank data is sent. I've implemented 'preventDefault' to avoid the form from being submitted, but the issue persists randomly. For validation, I've used the JavaScript code provided below. Additionally, upon successful validation and submission by the user, the form redirects to another page.

HTML Code:

```
<form class="registration-form">
   <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <label class="sr-only" for="form-name">First name</label>
      <input type="text" name="form-name" id="form-name" placeholder="Your Full Name"
         class="form-name form-control-lg form-control" id="form-name">
      <div class="valid-feedback valid-invalid">Valid</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback valid-invalid">Please Enter a valid Name</div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
      <input type="text" name="form-email" id="form-email" placeholder="Email Address"
         class="form-email form-control-lg form-control" id="form-email">
      <div class="valid-feedback valid-invalid">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback valid-invalid">Please Enter a valid Email Address</div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group mb-3">
      <label class="sr-only" for="form-phone">Phone</label>
      <input type="text" name="form-phone" id="form-phone" placeholder="Mobile Number"
         class="form-phone form-control-lg form-control" id="form-phone">
      <div class="valid-feedback valid-invalid">Valid.</div>
      <div class="invalid-feedback valid-invalid">Please Enter a valid Phone Number</div>
   </div>
   <button type="submit" id="formSubmit"
      class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block mt-2 shadow-lg">Submit
   Now</button>
</form>
```

JS code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  (function () {
    emailjs.init("ignore");
  })();

  const button = document.getElementById("formSubmit");
  const name = document.getElementById("form-name");
  const email = document.getElementById("form-email");
  const phone = document.getElementById("form-phone");
  button.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    const data = {
      name: name.value.trim(),
      email: email.value.trim(),
      phone: phone.value.trim(),
    };

    if (name.value.trim() === "") {
      name.classList.remove("is-valid");
      name.classList.add("is-invalid");
    } else {
      name.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      name.classList.add("is-valid");
    }

    if (
      email.value
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|.(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        ) &&
      email.value.trim() !== ""
    ) {
      email.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      email.classList.add("is-valid");
    } else {
      email.classList.remove("is-valid");
      email.classList.add("is-invalid");
    }

    if (
      phone.value.trim().match(/^(0|91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}$/) &&
      phone.value.trim !== ""
    ) {
      phone.classList.remove("is-invalid");
      phone.classList.add("is-valid");
    } else {
      phone.classList.remove("is-valid");
      phone.classList.add("is-invalid");
    }

    if (
      name.value.trim() !== "" &&
      phone.value.trim().match(/^(0|91)?[6-9][0-9]{9}$/) &&
      phone.value.trim !== "" &&
      email.value
        .trim()
        .toLowerCase()
        .match(
          /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|.(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/
        ) &&
      email.value.trim() !== ""
    ) {
      emailjs
        .send("ignore", "ignore", data)
        .then(function (res) {});
      window.location = "https://example.com";
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to prevent the default behaviour on the form's `submit` event if you don't want it to submit, not on the button's click event.